# How do I remove the blue border on an image in an image map?

Tags: html, css

I've created an image map for an image in a newsletter. Every time I click the link area, a blue border appears around it (image below). Is there any way to stop this? I'm new to coding, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

This is my code:

```
<img src="1234.jpg" width="600" height="341" border="0" usemap="#map">

<map name="map">
<area shape="rect" coords="18,24,193,64" href="https://google.com/">
<area shape="rect" coords="212,23,388,287" href="https://google.com/">
<area shape="rect" coords="405,23,582,287" href="https://google.com/">
</map>
```

[Blue border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0220.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in CSS.

```
img {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Or as a style attribute:

```
<img src="1234.jpg" width="600" height="341" border="0" usemap="#map" style="outline: 0;">
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure whether it's something to do with the platform I'm using (MailChimp), but I don't think that's it. Will keep researching.

Comment: Can you zero out the margin and padding? style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;